# Creating an iterative google form with data from google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms, google-forms-api

I am trying to build a form where I could collect feedback from users. I have 20 items which a user tried saved in a google sheet with their user ID's, product names and product ID's.

I want to keep these same for all the 20 items and ask multiple questions after this one.

My form would look something like:

Name: John Smith
UserID: 001
ProductID: A001

[This is followed by a set of 20 questions for this productID].

In short, I want to save users time by auto populating the first 3 fields and it looks like I can do this. I just want them to answer product specific questions and then go to next product and so on.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Just to better understand, you want to build a custom form automatically for each user based on the Sheet's product data and also pre-populate their name and ID?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: My final form for all users will have 23 questions out of which 3 should be coming from the google sheets I already have.

Comment: You need to use [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) to create a dynamic form which integrate with your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get it done:

1. use the three-dot-menu in the upper-right corner
2. choose "Get pre-filled link"
3. Fill out all options / dropdowns you want to prefill
4. For freeform answers, use a clear placeholder like AAANSWERRR
5. Actually generate the URL, you end up w/ sth like ``` https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/``<some form id>/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.<some entry id>=Option+2&entry.<some entry id>=AAANSWERRR ```
6. it's easy to recognize Options (like "Option 2") and freeform
   answers (like "AAANSWERRR")
7. now you can create a formula like `=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<some form id>/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.<some entry id>=Option+2&entry.<some entry id>=",ENCODEURL(F14)))`
8. assuming cell F14 contains "hey there", you'll get `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<some form id>/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.<some entry id>=Option+2&entry.<some entry id>=hey%20there`

You can copy and paste the formula to as many rows as you want - and each link is outright click-able. Of course, you can pre-fill several fields as well.